# Display my website statistics with Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to display my statistics. I know how to use basicaly the Google Analytics API.

1. The user will authentificate with google
2. The user will see **HIS** statistics from his account.

But what I want is to show my statistics. I really don't understand the goal of the API f I can't display the **statistics from my account to other users**.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to integrate the Google Analytics API with your application, you must have a Google API console project and enable Analytics API. For more details [Google Analytics API Integration & Example](http://www.apinotes.com/blog/info/2017/google-analytics-api/MQ==)